# How to get + ... notation at the end of a serie sum

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}+\text{...}$

Wanted output with extra **+ ...** added to the series end

This is the output from the series with using `Normal`

`Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]]` = $x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

`Append[Normal@Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}], + ..]` ..gives error

Has probably to do that command `Append` is working on a sequenze ?

So, how to add +... to the end of series sum ?

Comment: Try: `Row[{Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]], "+ ..."}]`

Comment: Daniel Huber, thanks , Row command  for other uses too.

Answer (score 5):

> how to add +... to the end of series sum ?

```
ser = Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]] + \[Ellipsis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use Basic typesetting Pallettes

[image]

Comment: Nasser- thanks , how simple can it be :), ah there a special name for it Ellipsis
A easy thing also to do , is adding + ... after the series command , works too

Comment: @janhardo  You can not just add `+ ...` this will give syntax error. Also if you do `+ "..."` then the Latex comes out wrong. Only when using \[Ellipsis] will the Latex comes out correct, using \ldots

Comment: `@nasser` tested on this  serie Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]] + \[Ellipsis]
Strange, now it is not accepted anymore

Comment: @janhardo it works for me. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKf9I.png)    did you add the "\" before the "[Ellipsis]" ?

Comment: `@nasser` i did not used a \,but the working depends on how  the dots be typed.  
It works too adding the three dots via :  + esc ...esc